# iSpeech iPhone SDK for monotouch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, text-to-speech

Is there a way to use the iSpeech SDK for iPhone in my monotouch project? http://www.ispeech.org/developers/iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an [ObjectiveC library](http://www.ispeech.org/developer/iframe?src=/iphonesdkdoc/). The way to use this inside a MonoTouch project is to [create .NET bindings](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types) for the library.

There's [one reference](http://www.ispeech.org/forums/showthread.php/67-monotouch-wrapper-for-SDK) of this *already?* existing in their forums but I could not google it. You might want to ask them (iSpeech) if they are aware of it before starting your own bindings.